# Ajax post multiple objects and Retrieve in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form and an array containing some data. I am trying to post both these objects to my php script. The code I am using to post the form and array is shown below:

```
var json_data = JSON.stringify(data_vendor); //array to be posted

$.ajax({                                      
  url: '/crm/inventory/add_purchase_order.php',              
  type: 'POST',   
  data: {data_vendor:json_data,form_data:$("#purchase_orderform").serialize()},     
  dataType: 'json',
```

In the PHP script I am able to decode the array using the following :

```
  $vendor_codes = json_decode($_POST["data_vendor"],true);
```

The form contains several fields/inputs one of which is called "order_quantity" . I am trying to retrieve this value using:

```
$order_quantity = $_POST["order_quantity"];
```

The data read shows up as NULL.

(i) Is the method used correct for posting multiple objects/strings correct?
(ii) Is the method used to retrieve the form inputs correct?

Comment: Is order_quantity nested into form_data? You could try `$_POST['form_data']['order_quantity']` then.

Comment: If you've decoded the post, try $vendor_codes['order_quantity'].

Comment: neither of the 2 above approaches work

Comment: Try $_POST["form_data"]["order_quantity"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you use `serialize()` that is all you send because it is a urlencoded string. Then the form control names  are available as keys in `$_POST`

But you currently only have 2 keys available to $_POST ... `$_POST["data_vendor"]` and `$_POST["form_data"]`

`$_POST["form_data"]` is a urlencoded string which you did with `serialize()` so it also needs to be decoded now manually

Try

```
$formData = urldecode($_POST["form_data"]);
$order_quantity = $formData ['order_quantity'];
```

To validate this just do a dump of `$_POST["form_data"]` and you will see that it is a string...not array

Comment: You're thinking about parse_str

Comment: @Musa   Indeed $_POST["form_data"] returns the ajax string posted for the serialized form :  &order_quantity=43& ....However I am unable to retrieve the individual items from the string;  '$order_quantity = $formData ['order_quantity'];'  returns the letter o. plz assists

Comment: might be simpler to use `JSON.stringify($("#purchase_orderform").serializArray())` in js and use json_decode in back end

Comment: @Musa             Thnx for the tip. ive got it to work :         `parse_str($_POST["form_data"],$formData);
    $order_quantity = $formData ['order_quantity'];`